# I need help sorting Dates from a SQL Server table and stuffing them in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need help sorting dates in chronological order and stuffing them into a string.

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US')) 
                    FROM JobScheduleDate
                    WHERE WorkDate >= '12/26/2017' AND WorkDate <= '01/23/2018'
                    ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US')) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
PRINT @cols
```

The JobScheduleDate table has the following dates:

```
12/26/2017
12/27/2017
12/28/2017
12/29/2017
1/1/2018
1/2/2018
1/3/2018
1/4/2018
1/5/2018
1/8/2018
1/9/2018
1/10/2018
1/11/2018
1/12/2018
1/15/2018
1/16/2018
1/17/2018
1/18/2018
1/19/2018
1/22/2018
1/23/2018
```

My results are as follows:

```
[1/10/2018],[1/11/2018],[1/12/2018],[1/16/2018],[1/17/2018],[1/18/2018],
1/19/2018],[1/2/2018],[1/22/2018],[1/23/2018],[1/3/2018],[1/4/2018],
[1/5/2018],[1/8/2018],[1/9/2018],[12/26/2017],[12/27/2017],[12/28/2017],[12/29/2017]
```

Comment: The result must be in the format M/d/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to format the dates using ANSI-standard format:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'yyyy-M-d', 'en-US')) 
                      FROM JobScheduleDate
                      WHERE WorkDate >= '2017-12-26' AND WorkDate <= '2018-01-23'
                      ORDER BY ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'yyyy-M-d', 'en-US')) 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'');
```

That would be my first recommendation.  You can also do this using your format:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US')) 
                      FROM JobScheduleDate
                      WHERE WorkDate >= '2017-12-26' AND WorkDate <= '2018-01-23'
                      GROUP BY ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US'))
                      ORDER BY MIN(WorkDate)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

This assumes that `WorkDate` is a date.  If it has a time component, then use `CAST(WorkDate as date)` for the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Your first suggestion works fine with a ANSI-standard format (and I can remove all formatting and get the same results), but I need to format the date in mm/dd/yyyy,  
Your second suggestion doesn't work as WorkDate is not in the SELECT DISTINCT statement

Comment: Remove the `DISTINCT` on the second query. You don't need it since you are already grouping by the same expression. However, I think it should also work when grouping simply by `WorkDate` (or `CAST(WorkDate as Date)` if it contains a time component.

Comment: Removing DISTINCT did the trick.  You are also correct in it worked with just GROUP BY WorkDate.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US')) 
                    FROM (select * from JobScheduleDate WHERE WorkDate >= '12/26/2017' AND WorkDate <= '01/23/2018' order by WorkDate) JobScheduleDate 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

You should retrieve the data from ordered set by `WorkDate ASC`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use workdate without string formating

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(WorkDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US')) 
                    FROM JobScheduleDate
                    WHERE WorkDate >= '12/26/2017' AND WorkDate <= '01/23/2018'
                    ORDER BY WorkDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
PRINT @cols
```

Comment: Doesn't work: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.